# Python BackgroundScheduler program crashing when ran from another module

Tags: python, multithreading, gtk, pygtk, apscheduler

I am trying to build a application that will run a bash script every 10 minutes. I am using  apscheduler to accomplish this and when i run my code from terminal it works like clock work. However when i try to run the code from another module it crashes i suspect that the calling module is waiting for the "schedule" module to finish and then crash when that never happens.

Error code

```
/bin/bash: line 1: 13613 Killed                  ( python ) < /tmp/vIZsEfp/26

shell returned 137
```

Function that calls schedule

```
   def shedual_toggled(self,widget):
            prosessSchedular.start_background_checker()
```

Schedule Program

```
def schedul_check(): 
    """set up to call prosess checker every 10 mins"""
    print "%s check ran" %(counter) 
    counter =+ 1

    app = prosessCheckerv3.call_bash() < calls the bash file
    if app == False:
        print "error with bash" 
        return False 
    else:
        prosessCheckerv3.build_snap_shot(app)


def start_background_checker():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(schedul_check, 'interval', minutes=10)
    scheduler.start()

    while True:
        time.sleep(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_background_checker()
```

this program simply calls another ever 10 mins. As a side note i have been trying to stay as far away from multi-threading as possible but if that is required so be it.

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to figure it out my self. The issue that GTK+ is not thread safe so the timed module need to be either be ran in another thread or else you can realise/enter the thread before/after calling the module.

I just did it like this.

```
def shedual_toggeld(self,widget):
        onOffSwitch = widget.get_active()

        """ After main GTK has logicly finished all GUI work run thread on toggel button """
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.call_schedual, args=(onOffSwitch,))
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()



    def call_schedual(self, onOffSwitch):
        if onOffSwitch == True:
            self.sch.start_background_checker()
        else:
            self.sch.stop_background_checker()
```

This article goes through it in more detail. Hopefully some one else will find this useful.
http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/gnome-desktop/gtk-thread-awareness